# Perl, cannot require a module dynamicaly from @INC

Tags: perl, package

So, i've got a problem with loading a module via `require`. 
We have a working directory. The program loads a **PACKAGE** (bolded not to make you confused) (which is ok - thanks to correct and local namespaces), but it has to load another module from very different directory. So, as i've heard, it should be unshifted into `@INC` in `BEGIN` block. But....This begin should take a param (currently from initial programm), containing some path to configuration file, which containing parameter i need (path to module, which i need to unshift).

`BEGIN` inited, i check @INC - unshift seems to be succeed. Then, in **PACKAGE** methods we need to load this module, but when i try to do something like:

```
eval{
    print STDERR "Trying...\n";
    my $path = "path/to/module"; # contains "DIR" dir and "Module.pm", 
    # also tried to write this path as "path/to/module/DIR/Module.pm"
    require $path;
    DIR::Module->import();
    print STDERR "Success\n";
    1;
} or {print STDERR "Failed\n";}

my $module = DIR::Module->new();
```

And I got "Trying.." and "Failed". Tried `use lib` with fullpath - got nothing. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

You say `$path` is the path to the module, but you also say it's the path to the directory containing `DIR/Module.pm`. I'm assuming it's the latter because it needs to be the former.

```
my $path = "/path/to/lib";
require "$path/DIR/Module.pm";
```

Remember to use `$RealBin` if the path is relative to your script.

```
use FindBin qw( $RealBin );

my $path = "$RealBin/../lib";
require "$path/DIR/Module.pm";
```

Note that it rarely makes sense to import from a dynamically loaded module.

---

If there's no reason to avoid loading this module at compile-time, I'd go with

```
use lib qw( /path/to/lib );
use DIR::Module;
```

Again, remember to use `$RealBin` if the path is relative to your script.

```
use FindBin qw( $RealBin );
use lib "$RealBin/../lib";
use DIR::Module;
```

Comment: I need to load on the run (`require`). So: in my current situation, `$path` is a fullpath from root directory to module. Do we need to use RealBin even in this stuation? And should i DIR::Module->import() to use its methods?

Comment: i also need to use its methods in initial progarmm, so, i think i need import, but i have problems with namespace

Comment: If they are methods (i.e. if they're called as `$class->method` or `$object->method`), it makes no sense for them to be exported.

Comment: Blessed ref of module